# supervisord graceful shutdown issue in kubernetes

Tags: laravel, docker, kubernetes, devops, supervisord

I'm facing an issue with supervisor & kubernetes.

Below is my supervisor config for laravel queue worker.

```
[program:queue-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work --sleep=10 --tries=3 --max-time=3600 --timeout=90 --daemon
user=nobody
autostart=true
autorestart=false
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/queue-worker.log
stopwaitsecs=50
stopsignal=TERM
```

when my container is terminating, a supervisor is still running in the background. It is not listing to the SIGTERM from Kubernetes.

if I try to stop using the preStop hook from Kubernetes and run the command `/usr/bin/supervisorctl stop queue-worker:*` then it stops immediately without waiting for 50 sec as mentioned in config.

Comment: Do you actually need supervisord here?  Can you just run `artisan queue:work` (without `--daemon`) as the main container `CMD`?

Comment: I also have PHP-fpm running in the container. so i'm runnnig queue & php-fpm using supervisor @DavidMaze

Comment: Is your container image publicly available so I could try to repicate this?

Comment: No, I don't have an image publicly available. But I was able to resolve the issue. To resolve the issue, I'm starting Nginx and PHP-fpm with the worker using a supervisor. So basically supervisor has PID 1 and it will receive SIGTERM before the pod stops.

Comment: Could you provide the asnwer in answers section? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, I'm started Nginx and PHP-fpm with the worker using a supervisor. So basically supervisor has PID 1 and it will receive SIGTERM before the pod stops from Kubernetes.

**Note:** Kubernetes send SIGTERM signal only to Process with ID 1. No child process receives a SIGTERM signal. If you want to send SIGTERM or any other POSIX signal to the process, then you can use the **preStop** hook.